# Change color of SwipeDelegate when pressed

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I have a simple Qt Quick application containing a [ListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) with a few [SwipeDelegates](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-swipedelegate.html).

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        id: list
        anchors.fill: parent

        model: ListModel {
            id: listView
            ListElement { name: "Element 1" }
            ListElement { name: "Element 2" }
            ListElement { name: "Element 3" }
            ListElement { name: "Element 4" }
        }

        delegate: SwipeDelegate {

            contentItem: Text {
                width: parent.width
                text: name
            }

            swipe.right: Label {
                id: deleteLabel
                text: qsTr("Delete")
                color: "white"
                verticalAlignment: Label.AlignVCenter
                padding: 12
                height: parent.height
                anchors.right: parent.right

                background: Rectangle {
                    color: deleteLabel.SwipeDelegate.pressed ? Qt.darker("tomato", 1.1) : "tomato"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Without setting any background color they show up with a grey background which gets darker if I press (or press and hold) an item:

[image]

I want to change that 'highlighted' color to something else, for example green. I was hoping setting the background color based on the onPressed event would help me, but adding `background: Rectangle { color: "green" }` to the SwipeDelegate as a test removes the darker 'highlight' on pressing entirely.

Is there a way to customize the highlight color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a style that [supports palettes](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-63331), you can set the relevant palette role. For the Default style ("Basic" in Qt 6), it assigns its background colour [like so](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols2.git/tree/src/imports/controls/ItemDelegate.qml?h=5.15#n74):

```
    color: Color.blend(control.down ? control.palette.midlight : control.palette.light,
                       control.palette.highlight, control.visualFocus ? 0.15 : 0.0)
```

So if you're using that style, you can set that property on the delegate:

```
palette.midlight: "green"
```

If the style doesn't support palettes, you have a few options:

1. Create a [Binding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-binding.html) to the relevant property.
2. Assign a colour in [Component.onCompleted](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#completed-signal).
3. Write your own [background](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-itemdelegate).

Comment: Setting the palette worked! Thank you very much, especially for the links!